# Android widget is not coming in the home screen

Tags: android, android-widget

I created a widget in android but it is showing me the error `Could not load widget`. I googled the error and in most of the websites they say widgets can only support buttons chronometers etc. I have a button and still its not working. can somebody please help me.

Comment: More details please: show your code for the widget.

Comment: here is my maifest file

Comment: Look at LogCat for a stack trace, as probably some code crashed in your `AppWidgetProvider`.